# Storyboard did not loading automatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I had an universal app for ipad and iphone and it wasn't using any storyboards. But recently I had moved all my xib files into storyboards. I have referenced all the outlet and action connection to the storyboard view controller also.

I have set the MainStoryBoradBasename(iPad) and iphone also in the info tab of the app in xcode 5

Then I deleted my code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: in appdelegate but it shows blank screen.All tutorials say there is no need no specify the `rootviewcontroller` while using storyboard
(Note : I have also set my `isinitialviewcontroller` in storyboard by checking it). 
But if I set `window.rootviewcontroller` to my initial view controller in stroyboard on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` everything work perfectly and when I removed it it shows blank screen.Is there any additional setting needed in xcode 5??

Comment: in *-info.plist do you see UIMainStoryboardFile?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Few key points to be followed while developing iOS app with Storyboard

Considering Main_iPhone.storyboard and Main_iPad.storyboard are the two storyboard files for iPhone and iPad respectively.

1. In '-*info.plist' set property as below,
   **Main storyboard file base name = Main_iPhone 

   Main storyboard file base name (iPad) = Main_iPad**
2. Under Project Setting, 
   **Choose target (App)> General > Deployment Info > iPhone  : Main Interface = Main_iPhone

   Choose target (App)> General > Deployment Info > iPad : Main Interface = Main_iPad**
3. In the Storyboard, set (checkbox) ***Is Initial View Controller = YES *** in controller which is supposed to be presented as FirstViewController/RootViewController.